# Cannot run DXA version 2.2.32 on localhost

Tags: dxa

We have upgraded our DXA version in our Java application to version 2.2.32 to fix a vulnerability, but we now find that running the application on localhost (development workstations) gives the generic "LocalizationNotFoundException". When backing the DXA version to 2.2.28, we can once again run locally, but changing the pom file back and forth is tedious, and we would like to find a solution. We are running the application on Java 8, in the embedded tomcat server in Spring Boot version 2.7.11, using Tridion 9.5.

We have engaged our support with RWS, but they were unable to offer any suggestions or solution.

Here is some of the exception from the DEBUG log:
com.sdl.webapp.common.api.localization.LocalizationNotFoundException: Localization not found for http://localhost:8080/dev/tiles-test
at com.sdl.webapp.common.impl.WebRequestContextImpl.localization(WebRequestContextImpl.java:256)
at com.sdl.webapp.common.impl.WebRequestContextImpl.getLocalization(WebRequestContextImpl.java:86)
at com.sdl.webapp.common.impl.WebRequestContextImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$2bfec188.invoke()
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:793)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)

Has anyone else seen anything similar and / or have a solution?

Comment: This normally means it cannot match the URL requested to a given website mapping. Adding http://localhost:8080 to one of your website mappings should fix it. Example here: http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/using-and-debugging-dxa-with-web-8-5-on-amazon, about half-way through the article.

Comment: localhost:8080 does have a mapping. Using it on a Windows PC works fine, just not on a Mac.